# Negation of $\exists x \forall y((y > x) \land (x = 3y))$

Tags: logic, proof-verification, quantifiers

I was wondering if someone could tell me if my answer & working out is correct as I don't have access to the answer. I am to find the negation of $\exists x \forall y((y > x) \land (x = 3y)$ :
$$ 
= \forall x \neg \forall y((y > x) \land (x = 3y)) 
\\
\iff  \forall x \neg \forall y((y > x) \land (x = 3y)) 
\\
\iff \forall x \exists y \neg ((y > x) \land (x = 3y)) 
\\
\iff \forall x \exists y(\neg(y > x) \vee \neg(x = 3y)) \\
\iff \forall x \exists y((y \leqslant x) \vee (x \neq 3y))
$$

Is $$\forall x \exists y((y \leqslant x) \vee (x \neq 3y))$$ negation of $$\exists x \forall y((y > x) \land (x = 3y))$$ ?

If I am incorrect please do tell me where I went wrong, thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the negation of $P\lor Q$? What about the negation of $a=b$?

Comment: Are we to find the negation of $\exists x \forall y((y > x) \lor (x = 3y))$ or the negation of $\exists x \forall y((y > x) \land (x = 3y))$? I'm getting tired with all these questions whose title doesn't match their inner text.

Comment: $\neg P \land \neg Q$ and $a \neq b$ ?

Comment: Let me fix that, sorry ** Fixed

Comment: You replied back with `a\not b` in a comment answer to GitGud.  Perhaps you mean `a\neq b` instead?

Comment: Yes, thank you for that @JMoravitz

Comment: So, if the negation of $a=b$ is $a\neq b$, what is the negation of $x=3y$?

Comment: $x \neq 3y$, that makes more sense, let me edit my answer (thank you) ** Changed my answer

Comment: Now your final result is correct, but there is some cleaning up to do in getting there.  You have a mysterious $a$ which appeared in the first three lines in place of $x$, and your second line mysteriously changed to a $\vee$ instead of a $\wedge$ before anything should have affected it.  Edit: Still one last $a$ to replace.

Comment: @JMoravitz Just fixed both them, thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Dear Samir Your answer is complete.

Comment: Informally, or semi-formally, you are OK. Over a fully formal language, one cannot in principle use $\not=$. Also, $a\le b$ may not be the negation of $a\gt b$. The language may not have $\le$, and over a partially ordered set $a\le b$ is not the negation of $a\gt b$.  So over a formal language one cannot do anything significantly different from $\lnot(\phi\land\psi)$ is equivalent to $\lnot\phi\lor \lnot\psi$, after taking care of the quantifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *Andre* said, your answer is roughly correct except for two things:

1. "$t \ne u$" denotes a short-hand for "$\neg( t = u )$" if the formal system does not natively support the symbol "$\ne$". This may seem silly, but many textbooks and references on logic define formal systems with equality but without the unequal symbol. Why? Simply because we don't need that and it makes it harder to prove facts **about the formal system itself**. Nevertheless, in actual mathematical practice it is far simpler to **have and use** "$\ne$".
2. "$t \le u$" normally denotes a short-hand for "$t < u \lor t = u$", and "$t > u$" is a short-hand for "$u < t$". If this is the case for your formal system, then it is not obvious that "$\neg( t > u )$" is equivalent to "$t \le u$". In fact, without further assumptions on the ordering, they may not be equivalent. If the domain is intended to be the real numbers, we do assume transitivity and irreflexivity and trichotomy (which are expressed by "$\forall x,y,z\ ( x < y \land y < z \to x < z )$" and "$\forall x\ ( \neg( x < x ) )$" and "$\forall x,y\ ( x < y \lor y < x \lor x = y )$"), in which case we can prove (try it!) that "$\neg( t > u )$" is equivalent to "$t \le u$" (the forward implication needs trichotomy while the backward implication needs transitivity and irreflexivity).